Neo4j seems to wrap a CALL query around cypher command
I am using Kafka Connect for first time on a standalone machine with locally hosted kafka broker and neo4j database running on the same . I am trying to ingest data into neo4j using custom cypher queries , however I get the following error .->
ERROR [neo4j-sink|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=neo4j-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:212)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:632)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:350)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:219)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.executeFailed(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:116)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.WorkerErrantRecordReporter.report(WorkerErrantRecordReporter.java:109)
        at org.neo4j.connectors.kafka.sink.Neo4jSinkTask.processMessages(Neo4jSinkTask.kt:73)
        at org.neo4j.connectors.kafka.sink.Neo4jSinkTask.put(Neo4jSinkTask.kt:49)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:601)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be a RETURN clause, a FINISH clause, an update clause, a unit subquery call, or a procedure call with no YIELD). (line 1, column 165 (offset: 164))
"UNWIND $events AS message WITH message.value AS event, message.timestamp AS __timestamp, message.header AS __header, message.key AS __key, message.value AS __value CALL {WITH * CREATE (n:Test {timestamp: __value.timestamp}) RETURN n}"

My Configuration file for kafka connect here is just a test file which contains the following ->
name=neo4j-sink                                                                 
connector.class=org.neo4j.connectors.kafka.sink.Neo4jConnector                  
#connector.class=streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector                  
tasks.max=1                                                                     
                                                                                
# Kafka configuration                                                           
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092                                                
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter                           
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter                         
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081                         
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081                       
                                                                                
errors.tolerance=none                                                           
errors.log.enable=true                                                          
errors.log.include.messages=true                                                
                                                                                
# Topic configuration                                                           
topics=<topic_name>
# Neo4j connection                                                              
neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687                                                 
neo4j.authentication.basic.username=<usename>                                       
neo4j.authentication.basic.password=<pass>                                    
                                                                                
# Simplified Cypher query that just creates a Check node for each message       
neo4j.cypher.topic.<topic_name>0=CREATE (n:Test {timestamp: __value.timestamp}) RETURN n

Could someone help me with why my query being wrapped around by a CALL statement . and how does it expect me to give a RETURN to the same. Or am I missing something ?
This file is just a test file and I expected for a new node of TEST type to be formed for every message . My original cypher query is pretty complex which involves multiple nested calls as well .

See the doc for the Kafka connector's Cypher strategy. It shows shows an example with 3 topics, one of which is creates. At the bottom of the doc is an example of the code generated by the connector to execute the Cypher code configured earlier in the doc for the creates topic - it also starts with UNWIND $events AS message.
Your config file is defining the topic <topic_name>, which seems wrong. Also, your config file defines Cypher code for the topic <topic_name>0 (note the extra "0" at the end), which seems even more wrong.
Make sure you carefully follow the documentation.
